# Best Practice for loading data from server (Android App)

Tags: android, database, web-services, sqlite

I'm building an Android app, which should:
show some data, loaded from a server in the Internet.

At the moment I have a local `SQliteDB` used in my app where the data is stored, which should be displayed. I use this, because I want to be able to show the data, even if there is temporarily no internet connection available.

Next step I will work on inserting data in the local `SQliteDB` from a internet server. I thought about doing it this way:

*When app starts, check if internet is available. If yes, connect to a webservice (including username and password). The webservice should deliver the necessary data via json object to the app and I will update the local SQlite DB.*

My questions:
**Is this a good idea?**
**Are there any better ways to do this?**

The data can be viewed (and edited) by a Zend Website, too.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you put it seems optimal. Maybe you should set a flag or alert which is time or date related..in case the app starts too many times without internet.

> **>>** For updates to your mobile app, you should consider the priority/urgency of having the same data on the server and your app.

**>** For the better ways to do it, you can opt the way which suits your requirement better.

**To fetch the data** in one thread and render it in another,

**1.** Write custom `Asynctasks`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

**OR**

**2.** Use something like AsyncHttpClient:  http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
where you get `onSuccess` and `onFailure` methods to work with the response.

The option *2.* is better if you just want to fetch data without doing anything else, and work on it, or save it. For the same, you need to parse the response first.

**To parse your data:**
As your response is `JSON` format, you may be better off using `Gson` to map data and with custom model classes. Eg.:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ModelClass modelClass= new ModelClass();
    modelClass= gson.fromJson(responseContent,ModelClass.class); 
//where responseContent is your jsonString
    Log.i("Web service response", ""+modelClass.toString());
```

More on: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

For Naming discrepancies(according to the variables in webservice), can use annotations like 
`@SerializedName`.

Use a for each loop  to verify/browse/access the data that would be populated in/as objects/fields of your model class:
Check these for doubts:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html
[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

**Now about saving your data:**

> **>>** It depends a lot on what the data from server is and how much data do you want to store.

In Android Storage Options:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

**a.** There's Shared Preferences:
These are good for saving/storing data which would be relatively small in size and could be overwritten and fetched frequently. **Eg.** username, current user's details, password
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

**b.** Maintaining a database is good for the larger chunk needed in your app.
You can store, update or over-write the data according to your need. There can be multiple tables or more data could be stored in various fields.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

While you use `Gson`, you also have the option of populating the objects of model class and then storing that response in a `String`(maybe in `SharedPreferences`, depending on length/size) using `gsonToJson` method. I have used that, cheeky but effective.

You need to consider other stuff too, pertaining to UI and memory optimization, `ListViews` or layouts etc depending on your app and its control flow.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a thread and get new data on loading the app. If you decide this path we had nice results with JSON using the Volley Project.

You can see a walk through here http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-volley-library-example.html

and get the code here
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library:-
https://github.com/Abhishekpalodath/FetchServerUtil-Android.git.
You can also load real-time data from the server by using this.